# Contact form with login

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to make a contact form in wordpress with a login - the contact form have to remember the users informations.

id - this is what they only need to fill once.

name
company
address

Comment: Please elaborate,  you want contact form available only to logged in users?

Comment: No it have to been available for all. But next time they have to send something, they only have to type the id :)

Comment: I see. For logged in users you don't want them to fill name, email etc again. It should be pre filled for the current logged in user,  right?  Please look into JetPack plugin's contact form module.  It already have this behavior.  You may need to custom code other fields like Company etc.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, i will look into this